# Como ejecutar una funcion escrita en php que recibe datos de cajas de texto desde un boton en otro formulario

Tags: php, javascript

He buscado por un sin numero de paginas y casi tengo la respuesta correcta , pero falta algo:
lo que pasa es que yo ejecuto una funcion(Guardar()) en una pagina(registrar_cliente.php), ahora, lo que que quiero hacer es que en mi otra pagina(cliente.php) mediante un boton solo me ejecute la funcion mas no que me direccione a la segunda pagina y lo ejecute.
Lo pude lograr pero, al ejecutarlo es como si no estuviera jalando los datos de las cajas de texto.y me sale un error de base de datos que seria logico al no digitar el dni , pero si lo digito.
ESTE ES EL CODIGO:

registrar_cliente.php

```
<?php
function Guardar()
{
    $Conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','12345678','prayci');
  $name= $_POST["Name"];
    $dni=$_POST["DNI"];
  $direccion= $_POST["Direccion"];
  $mysql = 'CALL Registrar_Cliente(?, ?, ?, @p_mensaje);';
  $stmt = $Conexion->prepare($mysql);
  $stmt->bind_param('sis',$name,$dni,$direccion);
  $stmt->execute();
  //variable de salida
   $select = mysqli_query($Conexion,'SELECT @p_mensaje');
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
   $mensaje = $result['@p_mensaje'];
   echo ($mensaje);
}



  ?>



cliente.php
<script>
     $(function() {
                      $("#submit").click(function() {
                       alert("<?php  echo Guardar();?>");
                         });
                      });                
</script>
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo que tienes que utilizar es AJAX.

```js
$('#IDFORMULARIO').submit(function(event){   //donde #IDFORMULARIO es el id del formulario de registro
      var parametros = $(this).serialize(); //esto se encarga de obtener todas los datos ingresados
      $.ajax({ //la llamada ajax
        type: "POST", 
        url: "registrar_cliente.php", //el archivo donde se encuentra el código a ejecutar
        data: parametros, //los datos ingresas en el formulario lo envías aquí
        success: function(data) {
          $('#resultado').html(data); //donde #resultado es el div donde se muestra el mensaje
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault(); //previene que el boton submit realice su comportamiento normal
    });
```

```html
<form role="form" id="IDFORMULARIO" method="post" autocomplete="off">

  <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" name="name" required>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="validate" name="DNI">
  <label for="DNI">DNI</label>
  <input type="text" class="validate" name="Direccion">
  <label for="Direccion">Direccion</label>
                 
  <div>
    <input class="btn right" type="submit" value="Registrar">
  </div>
              
</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Compañero, una consulta en la parte del ajax donde dice data, me indicas que deberia poner los parametros que le enviare al fichero donde esta la funcion en php? pero en esa funcion ya recibe con metodo post las variables de la pagina de mi formulario a registrar.. es necesario ponerlos? y si es necesario como lo pondria ahi ? entre comillas? o comillas simples? le pongo el id de los inputs?

Comment: Compañero.... gracias por tu ayuda ya lo hize y funciono ahora quiero ver la manera de que el mensaje se mande como una alerta mas no como un mensaje echo, lo revisare y si tienen alguna ayuda estare presto a verlass de todas maneras agradecerte.

Comment: ya lo hize xDD ya esta funcionanado como yo lo esperaba, gracias nuevamente :)